# measure difference between two distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution

I have a distance vector of a sample program. I am trying to quantify how similar they are. I was using Euclidean distance between sample groups (each value belongs to a bucket, we compare bucket by bucket), which works fine. But there are too many comparisons that needs to be done for large number of samples.

I was wondering if there is a efficient way to build an index to compare the samples.  The samples look like this--

```
Sample:1 = {25 0 17 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
Sample:2 = {25 1 16 2 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
Sample:3 = {25 3 16 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
```

Answer (score 10):

There exist many ways to characterise the "difference between two distributions". A specific and targeted answer requires more details concerning e.g. the underlying probability distribution(s).

It all depends on how you *define* a difference between two distributions. To give you two ideas:

1. A [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) is a non-parametric test, that measures the "distance" between two cumulative/empirical distribution functions.
2. The [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) measures the "distance" between two distributions in the language of information theory as a change in entropy.

---

### Update [a year later]

Upon revisiting this post it might be important to emphasise a few things:

1. The standard two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test assumes the underlying distribution to be *continuous*. For *discrete* data (which the data from the original post seems to be), an alternative may be to use a bootstrap version of the two-sample KS test, as in `Matching::ks.boot`. More details can be found on e.g. [Cross Validated: *Can I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov to compare two empirical distributions?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/can-i-use-kolmogorov-smirnov-to-compare-two-empirical-distributions) and on [Wikipedia: Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).
2. Provided the sample data in the original post is representative, I don't think there will be a very meaningful answer from either a KS-statistic based test or the KL divergence (or really any other test for that matter). The reason being that the values from every sample are essentially all zero (to be precise, >80% of the values are zero). That in combination with the small sample size of 21 values per sample means that there is really not a lot "left" to characterise any underlying distribution.
3. In more general terms (and ignoring the limitations pointed out in the previous point), to calculate the KL divergence for all pairwise combinations one could do the following

   ```
   library(entropy)
   library(tidyverse)
   expand.grid(1:length(lst), 1:length(lst)) %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(KL = KL.empirical(lst[[Var1]], lst[[Var2]]))
   ```

   Since the KL divergence is not symmetric, we will need to calculate both the upper *and* lower triangular parts of the pairwise KL divergence matrix. In the interest of reducing compute time one could instead make use of a [symmetrised KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Symmetrised_divergence), which requires calculating the KL divergence only for the upper *or* lower triangular parts of the pairwise KL divergence matrix (although the symmetrised KL divergence versions themselves require calculating both KL divergences, i.e. `KL(1->2)` and `KL(2->1)` but this may be done through an optimised routine).

Comment: The observations are independent and we don't want to touch the distributions more than once, as we have millions of them. 
I tried using Kullback-Leibler divergence, I am not sure how to interpret how meaningful the differences are.

Comment: @JoyBangla I'm not sure what you're asking. Millions of observations is not a lot to dramatically affect computational time. If you want to establish a similarity measure between different distributions, run pairwise KS tests. Ditto for pairwise KL divergences. I'm not sure what you mean by *"to interpret how meaningful the differences are"*. This seems to be more of a (fundamental) stats question, in which case SO is not the right forum, and I recommend a basic stats textbook. See also [here](https://www.countbayesie.com/blog/2017/5/9/kullback-leibler-divergence-explained).

Comment: How about the Wasserstein distance?